# How to make API requests with loop in SAS

Tags: sql, api, sas, sas-macro, datastep

I'm trying to geocode entities (company) through the Brazilian zip code respectively, using a public API called [BrasilAPI](https://brasilapi.com.br/).

This is a fictional sample of the data:

```
data AMOSTRA_ENTIDADE;
infile datalines delimiter=',';
length  CODEMPRESA 3. 
        NOMEEMPRESA $9
        CEP $8;

input   CODEMPRESA 
        NOMEEMPRESA $
        CEP;
datalines;
1,EMPRESA A,71577090
2,EMPRESA B,01026010
10,EMPRESA C,01000000
100,EMPRESA D,92300000
110,EMPRESA E,29010580
;
run;
```

[fictional sample of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUk5m.png)

I recently discovered the http SAS proc for this task, I don't know if there is another one. With that I tried to make the following code snippet to perform the request in the API following these examples I found:

- [example_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64916718/how-can-i-send-receive-and-collect-data-to-and-from-api-in-a-loop-in-%20sas-eg)
- [example_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64699119/download-json-file-from-api-via-proxy-using-sas-eg/64699478#64699478)
- [example_3](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Looping-Through-API-Request/td-p/565574)

  ```
  %macro get_lat_long(cep);
    %let site="https://brasilapi.com.br/api/cep/v2/&cep.";
    %put NOTE: &site.;
    filename resp temp;

    proc http
       url = &site
       method = get
       out = resp;

       debug level=1;
    run;

    libname resp json;

    data _null_;
       infile resp;
       input;
       put _infile_;
    run;

  %mend get_lat_long;

  data COORDENADAS_ENTIDADE;
     set AMOSTRA_ENTIDADE;
     length macro_call $200;

     macro_call  = cats('%consulta_lat_long(',CEP,')');
     call execute(macro_call);
     rc = dosubl(macro_call);
  run;
  ```

return from the code above:
[image: output]

My question is, how to make these requests in SAS to return the JSON and other information coming from the request in the API?

What I have input:
[image: input]

What I'm looking for in the output:
[image: expected output]

Please, if possible, I would like examples to run on both SAS Enterprise Guide and SAS Viya. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I am not sure I understand what part you are having issues with.  Does the PROC HTTP call work for one example value of CEP?  If so then what is the question? If not then explain what is not working.

Comment: Yes, it's working for a value in the API call.

My question is how to loop in the CEP column of the dataset with the macro and return the JSON in a column as a string with the result of the API call.

Comment: The API returns a JSON file.  If you want to capture the JSON file into a variable you need to actually read the file after you have created it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good start but you weren't reading in the JSON at all. This should give you a better idea of how to loop this, but it currently does not handle the case of a CEP not being found - I'll leave you to figure out that logic. Otherwise it does work to create a table with CEP + Coordinates you can merge. Rather than the JSON text, I suggest storing the ALLDATA from the JSON and reformat that to the required structured.

```
data AMOSTRA_ENTIDADE;
infile datalines delimiter=',';
length  CODEMPRESA 3. 
        NOMEEMPRESA $9
        CEP $8;

input   CODEMPRESA 
        NOMEEMPRESA $
        CEP;
datalines;
1,EMPRESA A,71577090
2,EMPRESA B,01026010
10,EMPRESA C,01000000
100,EMPRESA D,92300000
110,EMPRESA E,29010580
;
run;

proc sql;
drop table master_locations;
drop table master_allData;
quit;

%macro get_lat_long(cep);
  %let site="https://brasilapi.com.br/api/cep/v2/&CEP";
  %put NOTE: &site.;
  filename resp temp;

  proc http
     url = &site
     method = "get"
     out = resp;
  run;

  libname resp json;

  
  *keep all data if desired;
  data fullResponse;
      length Value $200.;
      set resp.allData;
      
  run;
  
  *get location coordinates from RESP library;
  data location;
      set resp.location_coordinates;
      CEP=&CEP.;    
  run;
  
  *append to master file;
  proc append base= master_locations data=location;
  run;
  
  proc append base=master_allData data=fullResponse;
  run;

  *remove temporary tables so you do not get wrong data between loops;  
  proc sql;
  drop table location;
  drop table fullresponse;
  quit;
  
  %mend get_lat_long;

  
  data COORDENADAS_ENTIDADE;
   set AMOSTRA_ENTIDADE;
   length macro_call $200;

   macro_call  = cats('%get_lat_long(',CEP,')');
   call execute(macro_call);
run;
```

Comment: Do not include unbalanced quotes in statement comments inside a macro definition.  The unbalanced quotes will confuse the macro processor.  `... so you do not get ...`

Comment: Thanks, added comments after posting but usually catch that in the code for sure.

Comment: Ah yes, I get it, I thought that when trying to return the JSON text, I wouldn't need the JSON libname. I will follow as suggested, and work with ALLDATA, thanks for the tip!