# SAS API request produces "illegal character" error

Tags: api, rest, sas

I am trying to geocode addresses from within a company network with a proxy using a geocoder that requires a login. In the browser I needed to enter the login credentials only once on the first attempt.

I have used the code below for a different geocoder (without authentication) before, for which it worked just fine. I got it as an answer to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64699119/download-json-file-from-api-via-proxy-using-sas-eg/64699478#64699478). However, for this one it returns the following error:

```
59         * libref name same as fileref pointing to json content;
60         libname response json;
NOTE: JSON data is only read once.  To read the JSON again, reassign the JSON LIBNAME.
ERROR: Invalid JSON in input near line 1 column 1: Encountered an illegal character.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
```

Compared to the other code i just added `webusername` and `webpassword`, but whether I used it or not made no difference to the error message. Besides that, I only changed the URL of options `set=SSL_SNI_HOSTNAME` and `url=` of course.

```
filename response temp;
filename headers temp;

options set=SSL_USE_SNI=1;
options set=SSL_SNI_HOSTNAME="https://geocoder.srv"; /*<-- this might be wrong, i took it from the start of the url */
proc http
url = 'SORRY NOT ALLOWED TO PUT THE URL HERE'
method='GET'
proxyhost = 'OUR WEBPROXY'
webusername = 'USERNAME'
webpassword = 'PW'
proxyport = 8080
out= response
headerout = headers
ct = "application/json";
run;


data _null_;
  infile headers;
  input; 
  put _infile_;
run;

data _null_;
  infile response obs=10;
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;

* libref name same as fileref pointing to json content;
libname response json;

proc copy in=response out=work;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

This usually means something went wrong during the request and the site did not return a JSON file. To diagnose the returned message, add the `debug` statement ([info](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n0i2ek87s12e7mn1h2q3h0mywkl1.htm&locale=en)). Use the options `RESPONSE_BODY RESPONSE_TEXT` to return the response in the log.

```
proc http 
    url       = "www.google.com"
    proxyhost = "my proxy"
    proxyport = 8080
    ;
    debug RESPONSE_BODY OUTPUT_TEXT;
run;
```

Response:

```
< <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world's 
information, including webpages, images, videos and more.
....
```

You can simplify the response further by removing `RESPONSE_BODY`.

```
NOTE: 200 OK
```

If your version of SAS does not support these options, you can do the same thing by redirecting the response to your home directory and opening the file. For example:

```
filename response "/home/$USER/response.txt";

proc http
    url = "www.google.com"
    out = response
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Stu. Unfortunately, my version of SAS does not support the debug option. With your second option I get the error "physical file does not exist" ...could that be a missing permission?

Comment: Try pointing the response file to another location that you have read/write access to and can open it up.